# $\int_c^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\log(2+x^2)^\alpha}<\infty$ for $\alpha>1$ and $c\gg0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the integral $$\int_c^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\log(2+x^2)^\alpha}$$ for $\alpha>1$ and $c\gg 0$. Is there a simple way to see that this is finite? Clearly we cannot bound above by any power $x^{-\beta}$ for $\beta>1$. I wish to bound $$\frac{1}{x\log(2+x^2)^\alpha}\le\frac{1}{2^{-\alpha}x(\log x)^\alpha}$$ but I don't immediately see why we should have $$\int_c^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(\log x)^\alpha}<\infty$$ for $\alpha>1$.

Comment: For the last integral, just use a substitution with $u=\log x$ and it falls out immediately.

Comment: For the last bit, let $u = \log x$

Comment: I'm not sure $c=0$ is convergent. Might want to make that $c>0$

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be $c>1$. I corrected that typo.